# Run Asp.Net Core Web API in same port

Tags: asp.net-web-api, port

I have a lot of separate Web Api projects in my solution and I will call their endpoints from my angular project. But I want to run and deploy in same port from all my APIs.(For example: localhost:5000). How can I do this? I choose multiple startup solution in visual studio. But when I run project, it gave "same port" error.

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: Angular 5. But, important thing for me is, running all APIs from one port. If i achieve this, i can call from angular easily.

Comment: This does not make any sense. You really want to share one port with different services?

Comment: I can collect all these API's in one project. And then i can run this huge API project in one port. But i want split API projects. Besause if i don't split, this API project will be very huge. And then when a person (in my team) open visual studio, he can't unload unnecessary project. But if i split projects, every people can work with their necessary API project only.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your point. I cannot follow your argumentation. Hopefully someone else will help you.

Comment: Thanks for yor reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls(new[] { "http://localhost:5001", "http://localhost:5001" }) // edit this here
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, this code changing port. But, when I set Url of my 20 API to "localhost:5000";, I also cannot run all API in same time. Because, it says that "port is in use" when run the second one. I want host all 20 API in one URL like "localhost:5000";. Because, I don't want 5000,5002,5003,5004.....,5019. @BayramAkbuz